# How to pass access credentials in request with AWS API

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I'm trying to pass a request with AWS API but I get this error

```
AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials
```

My request is:

```
https://ec2.amazonaws.com/?Action=RunInstances&ImageId=ami-6df1e514&KeyName=key1&InstanceType=t2.micro&Placement.AvailabilityZone=us-west-2&AWSSecretAccessKey=**********************&AWSAccessKeyId=******************
```

My access credentials are right, there is no doubt about that. 
I found that the problem could be caused by clock delay but My PC's clock is correct.
Could someone help me, I did not find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **never** send your secret access key to AWS when making an API call. Instead, you sign your request with the access/secret keys (as described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/Query-Requests.html#query-authentication)). You can read more about signing [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html).

Ideally, use the [JavaScript SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/) rather than manually generating [query requests](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/Query-Requests.html).

You should also [rotate the credentials](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-rotate-access-keys-for-iam-users/) that you were using because you have exposed the secret key.

Comment: I have been informed that I am obliged to use the API and not the SDK so what I need is an example of a full request and how we could do authorization with the API. I have red a lot in the API reference and did find nothing.

Comment: There's a lot of information out there on this topic. For example: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signing_aws_api_requests.html

Answer (score 0):

Where did you find this way of authentication by passing access-key and secret-key as parameters?

AWS SDK like java-sdk or boto3 provide easy to use APIs to make such calls so I would recommend using them.

Also look at authentication mechanism required by AWS API calls:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html

Comment: What I found is to put only AWSAccessKeyId but when It didn't work I added the  AWSSecretAccessKey. If I pass the request without puting AWSAccessKeyId, I get the error: The request must contain the parameter AWSAccessKeyId. As you said, I'm trying to use javascript-sdk (nodeJS-sdk).